# manim add dots to circle list

Tags: python, manim

I am trying to create a bunch of circles around a bigger circle and the smaller circles need to have dots added to them. I am however struggling with adding the dots.

I believe it is because the object in the loop is a mobject and not a circle but I cannot figure out how to cast it, if this is indeed my issue.

Please help if you can

```
# manim scene.py PathExample
from manim import *

class PathExample(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        num_points = 16
        angles = [n * (360 / num_points) for n in range(num_points)]

        outer_circle = Circle(color=RED, radius=3)
        circles = [Circle(color=RED, radius=1).shift(4*LEFT).move_to(
        outer_circle.point_at_angle(n*DEGREES)) for n in angles]

        dots1 = []
        for c in circles:
            c.add_updater(lambda m: m.rotate(-0.01))
            dot = Dot(color=RED, radius=0, stroke_width=0).move_to(
                Circle(c).point_at_angle(0*DEGREES))
            dots1.append(dot)

        # # First attempt
        # dots1 = [Dot(color=RED, radius=0, stroke_width=0).move_to(
        #     c.point_at_angle(0*DEGREES)) for c in circles]

        rolling_outer_circle = VGroup(
            outer_circle, *circles)

        rolling_outer_circle.add_updater(lambda m: m.rotate(-0.01))
        self.add(rolling_outer_circle, outer_circle)
        self.play(rolling_outer_circle.animate, run_time=10, rate_func=linear)
        self.wait()
```

Executing
manim scene1.py PathExample

Comment: you could create minimal working code with all imports, etc. You could also draw manually expected result. At this moment we can't even run it to see what you get with this code.

Comment: Added minimal working code

Comment: meanwhile I tried to run your first code and problem makes `0*DEGREES`. If I use `n*DEGREES`(with `for c, n in zip(circles, angles)`) then it works for me. Other problem is that `Dot` has `radius=0, stroke_width=0` so it invisible. It needs ie. `radius=.01`

Comment: Yeah, I set the radius to 0 to fix another issue not related to this. There are three dots added but for minimal working code, I just did one. The three dots are evenly spaced at 0,120 and 240. My code works if I do the circles separately but I want to define them as an array to make code dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but main problem makes `point_at_angle(0*DEGREES)` - in some situations it gives wrong results.

If I use `n*DEGREES` with `for c, n in zip(circles, angles):` then it works.

Other problem is that `Dot` for `radius=.1, stroke_width=0` is invisible so it needs ie. `radius=.1`

---

Minimal working code

```
from manim import *

class PathExample(Scene):

    def construct(self):
        num_points = 16
        
        angles = [n * (360 / num_points) for n in range(num_points)]

        outer_circle = Circle(color=RED, radius=3)
        
        circles = [Circle(color=RED, radius=1).move_to(outer_circle.point_at_angle(n*DEGREES)) 
                    for n in angles]

        dots = []
        for c, n in zip(circles, angles):
            #c.add_updater(lambda m: m.rotate(-0.01))
            dot = Dot(color=RED, radius=.1, stroke_width=0).move_to(c.point_at_angle(n*DEGREES))
            dots.append(dot)

        # # First attempt
        #dots = [Dot(color=RED, radius=.1, stroke_width=0).move_to(c.point_at_angle(n*DEGREES)) 
        #            for c, n in zip(circles, angles)]

        rolling_outer_circle = VGroup(outer_circle, *circles, *dots)

        rolling_outer_circle.add_updater(lambda m: m.rotate(-0.01))
        
        self.add(rolling_outer_circle, outer_circle, *dots)
        self.play(rolling_outer_circle.animate, run_time=10, rate_func=linear)
        self.wait()
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import subprocess
    subprocess.run(['manim', '-p', '-ql', __file__, 'PathExample'])
```

Result (partial animation):

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Thank You furas!

Comment: Definitely not perfect but this is what I made https://youtu.be/2-aJja8DS8Y